# Fastest way to paste all rows together

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I want to paste all rows into the same cell column by column

For example, I have a table like as follows:

```r
library(tibble)

tibble::tribble(
  ~Col1, ~Col2, ~Col3,
  "AA",     "AA",    "AB",
  "AB",     "AB",    "BB",
  "BC",     "BB",    "AA"
  )
```

```
Col1  Col2  Col3

AA     AA    AB

AB     AB    BB
 
BC     BB    AA
```

The output I want is a 3X1 table as follows:

```
Col1 AAABBC

Col2 AAABBB

Col3 ABBBAA
```

However, the real case is more complicated because my original table has 600,000 rows and 2000 columns. I'm wondering what's the most rapid way of achieving this. I tried the loop but it took forever to finish pasting rows by columns.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough memory to store multiple instance of your data this approach using `doParallel` package could work. Here I am using `tidyverse` family.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(doParallel)

n <- 1000
# Generate a 1000 rows df with ~3000 columns
big_table <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, data, simplify = FALSE))
lapply(1:10, function(x) {big_table <<- bind_cols(big_table, big_table); return(x)})

# Get the list of column names
col_list <- names(big_table)
# Define number of cores you want to process
number_of_parallel_cores <- 4
col_group <- split(col_list, sort(rep_len(1:number_of_parallel_cores, length(col_list))))

# Running the code with timer
system.time({
  registerDoParallel(number_of_parallel_cores)
  combine_data <- bind_rows(foreach(i_col_group = col_group) %dopar% {
    big_table %>%
      select(one_of(i_col_group)) %>%
      summarize(across(.fns = paste, collapse = "")) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "col_names", values_to = "values")
  })
})
```

Timing

```
   user  system elapsed 
  1.291   0.291   0.898
```

Output

```
   col_names values                                                                                                                                                                                                               
   <chr>     <chr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 1 Col1...1  AAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAA…
 2 Col2...2  AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAA…
 3 Col3...3  ABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAAB…
 4 Col1...4  AAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAA…
 5 Col2...5  AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAA…
 6 Col3...6  ABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAAB…
 7 Col1...7  AAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAA…
 8 Col2...8  AAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAA…
 9 Col3...9  ABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAABBBAAAB…
10 Col1...10 AAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAAABBCAA…
# … with 3,062 more rows
```

**However I found that just simply bind all together is a lot faster comparing with parallel setup. Guess the overhead cost is not really feasible for this operations**

```
system.time(
  big_table %>%
    select(one_of(col_list)) %>%
    summarize(across(.fns = paste, collapse = "")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "col_names", values_to = "values")
)

   user  system elapsed 
  0.021   0.000   0.022
```

Comment: OMG, you're amazing. This is really helpful!!! Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- fread('Col1  Col2  Col3
AA     AA    AB
AB     AB    BB
BC     BB    AA')


transpose(dt)[,.(result=do.call(paste0,.SD))]
#>    result
#> 1: AAABBC
#> 2: AAABBB
#> 3: ABBBAA

#or


dt <- fread('Col1  Col2  Col3
AA     AA    AB
AB     AB    BB
BC     BB    AA')
transpose(dt[,paste0("new_cols",1:3) := lapply(.SD,paste,collapse="")][1,.SD,.SDcols = patterns("^new")])
#>        V1
#> 1: AAABBC
#> 2: AAABBB
#> 3: ABBBAA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

2nd method should be faster than the 1st one.

Answer (score 1):

```r
lapply(df, paste, collapse="")
```

This returns a list. If you want a vector, use `sapply` instead of `lapply`. If you want a data frame, wrap the entire call in `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `dapply` from `collapse` which is optimized for row wise operations

```
library(collapse)
dapply(df1, paste, collapse="", MARGIN = 1)
#[1] "AAAAAB" "ABABBB" "BCBBAA"
```

According to `?dapply`

> dapply efficiently applies functions to columns or rows of matrix-like objects and by default returns an object of the same type and with the same attributes. Alternatively it is possible to return the result in a plain matrix or data.frame. A simple parallelism is also available.